# MVC3 hierarchy and passing parent values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parent-child

Scenario:

Model: EntityA has 0:many EntityB has 0:many EntityC. So it's a three level hierarchy.
EntityB holds a reference to EntityA (by having EntityA_ID as property of EntityB) and EntityC holds a reference to EntityB (by having EntityB_ID as property of EntityC).

I have a controller for EntityA, a controller for EntityB and a controller for EntityC.
EntityB and EntityC are displayed through partial views that are rendered on the EntityA detail view.

I have the following problem:
After I create a new instance of EntityC, I want it to redirect to the details page of EntityA. But I can't because I don't have the ID of EntityA in the controller of EntityC, I only have the EntityB ID. How can I in some kind of way bubble up to end in the Detail view of EntityA, or How can I pass on the ID of EntityA all the way down to creation of EntityC.

I think I can do it to introduce EntityA_ID also as property of EntityC. But from a datamodelling perspective, that doesn't make sense. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Is this EF? Can't you just do `entityA.EntityB.EntityC.Id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I guess I should use the controller as it is supposed to be. Before redirecting I query the EntityB (for which I have the ID) to retrieve the ID of EntityA. And then pass this ID to the details view of entity A.

In case a better method is available, I am still looking for it.